# Get entity JPA Id after merge?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a freshly created entity (detached because not yet saved in the DB). This entity holds another entity that already exists in the db (but is detached, too). Thus, I would use `em.merge(myNewEntity)` to store it.

If I want to get the new created ID, I would use `em.flush()` afterwards. Then I invoke `myNewEntity.getId()`. With `persist` I receive an ID generted by the DB/JPA. With `merge`, it does not. The ID in the object remains `null`. Why is that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The result of the `merge` operation is not the same as with the `persist` operation - the entity passed to `merge` does not become managed. Rather, a managed copy of the entity is created and returned. This is why the original new entity will not get an id. So instead of

```
em.merge(newEntity);
Long id = newEntity.getId();
```

it should be

```
managedEntity = em.merge(newEntity);
Long id = managedEntity.getId();
```

Comment: easy guess in the crystal ball, right? However, thanks. It's documented and works as you proposed.